# The train or a train

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Fill in the blanks with a, the or no article.
___ train station is ____ strange building.
Why is it
"The train station is a strange building."
And not
"A train station is a strange building."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All 4 combinations are theoretically possible given the right context. Without a specific context only one makes sense - this particular train station ("the train station") is an example of "a strange building".

- "A train station is the strange building" - you are looking for "the strange building" and got "it is a train station" as a hint in your search. One of train stations is *the* building you are looking for.
- "The train station is the strange building" - this particular train station is the building you are talking about/looking for.
- "A train station is a strange building" - some sort of categorization of all train stations to be "strange" buildings. I don't expect this combination to be used in real life.

Comment: "*I don't expect this combination to be used in real life.*" — perhaps not for train stations, but in golf "A hole in one is a thing of wonder.". And musically, Patricia Ingalls wrote "*A gift of song is a gift of love".

Comment: Many British people object to '_train_ station', and would say that a railway station is just _a station_.